# How to stop a webpage from displaying message boxes?

Tags: windows, activex, message

We have third party software that displays video via a webpage. During the video it checks for a time stamp every second, it fails this check and we end up with a cascade of error messages.

The webpage incorporates it's own ActiveX controls and I am fairly sure the error is spawning inside one of them.

I have tried disabling windows error reporting with no luck(the error messages look just like a standard message box with a red X and ok button).

Is there any way to disable all message boxes coming from a website? a browser? or the entire computer?